# Remove permissions from long output of ls w/ sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to remove the permissions from ls -l with a regex.This is what im trying:

```
ls -l | sed '/^.([rwx]{9}) //'
```

It's not working and im not sure why?

Comment: doesnt work [rwx-] either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posix `sed` only allows "Basic" Regular Expressions, which don't include the `{n,m}` repetition syntax (among other things). The GNU version of `sed`, distributed with most linux distributions, enables "Extended" (i.e. normal) regular expressions if you use it with the `-r` option. BSD `sed` (eg. on Mac OS X) uses the `-E` flag for this purpose.

So on linux, you could write:

```
ls -l | sed -r 's/^.[-rwx]{9} //'
```

[Note 1]

But it would be a lot easier to do this with the standard `cut` utility:

```
ls -l | cut -c12-
```

which prints the characters of each line starting at character number 12.

Or, since Posix allows the first field of the `ls -l` listing to be 11 characters instead of 10, you could use `cut` to output all fields starting with the second one, using a space character as a delimiter (this needs to be specified because the `cut` default delimiter is tab):

```
ls -l | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

---

[1] This regular expression is too strict: it will fail to match the modes of setuid/setgid executables, restricted-deletion directories -- like `/tmp` -- and some anomalies. More accurate ones might be `^.[-rwxsStT]{9}` or `^.([-r][-w][-xsStT]){3}`. But be aware that Posix allows the last of the three characters in each group to be some other character, an also allows an additional "alternate access method flag" at the end of the mode groups.

Comment: the sed expression will puke on non-regular files, like directories, symlinks, sockets, device nodes, etc.  The cut method is good, but I personally prefer a field delimiter.

Comment: @grim: I think you missed the `.` at the beginning of the regex. It will fail on setuid/setgid executables, though. I should have mentioned that. The OP was "why doesn't this regex work?" so I tried to answer that using roughly the same regex.

Answer (score 2):

For these situations I like to use `cut` with a field delimiter.

```
ls -l | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

BASH only solutions are always good.

```
while read _ line; do echo $line; done < <(ls -l)
```

or `awk`

```
ls -l | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$2))}'
```

or `ruby`

```
ls -l | ruby -ane 'puts $F[1..$F.count].join(" ")'
```

Each prints each line starting from the second field.

Answer (score 1):

Try with 'cut' command.

```
ls -l |cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

-d specifies the field delimiter used. Here it is a 'space'. 2 after -f specifies to start with second collumn. '-' inicates, to cut till end of the line.